# Na.action = exclude error in lapply

Tags: r, loops, lapply, na, lm

I have a dataframe with 507 columns. The first column is the date of observation. Columns 2 through 504 are my dependent variables. The 505, 506, and 507 columns are the independent variables. I have written a functinon to do a separate regression for each of the dependent variables:

```
varlist<-names(df)[2:504]


models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(i ~ rmrf + smb + hml, na.action = na.exclude, list(i = as.name(x))), data = df)
})
```

The na.exclude parameter is giving me the following error code:

```
 Error in substitute(i ~ rmrf + smb + hml, na.action = na.exclude, list(i = as.name(x))) : unused argument (na.action = na.exclude)
```

However, the regressions work when I run each one separately.

```
lm(Var2 ~ rmrf + smb + hml, na.action = na.exclude, data = df)
```

What could be causing the error when I include the na.action parameter in the lapply function?

Comment: `lapply(varlist,function(x)lm(reformulate(c("rmrf","smb","hml"),x),na.action=na.exclude,data=df))`

Comment: `lapply(varlist,function(x)lm(paste0(x,"~rmrf+smb+hml"),na.action=na.exclude,data=df))`

Comment: This solution also works, but Rilcon42's solution explained to me the error I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parameters in the wrong order. To see the issue better try spacing your code out like this:

```
varlist<-names(df)[2:504]

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(
    substitute(i ~ rmrf + smb + hml, 
       na.action = na.exclude, 
       list(i = as.name(x))
    ), 
       data = df)
})
```

Notice how in the example that works

```
lm(Var2 ~ rmrf + smb + hml, na.action = na.exclude, data = df)
```

the `na.action` parameter is inside the lm function? In the example that doesnt work it is inside the substitute function

Comment: user6883405 Glad it was useful, if you wouldn't mind pressing the green checkmark next to the answer, that will mark it as "accepted" to show that is was useful in figuring out the problem